# PHP: autoloader can't find the file

Tags: php, autoloader

I'm using autoloader to load classes by their namespaces, it's working fine on localhost but not on server online.
When `Autoloader.php` loads classes PHP shows me this error :

```
Warning: require(\..\backoffice\controllers\EquipementsManager.php) failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

But I'm sure the path is correct and the file `EquipementsManager.php` exists in this path !Which means the autoloader is loading classes properly with the right path but PHP keeps giving me `No such file or directory` error !
Code of `Autoloader.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Class Autoloader
 */

class Autoloader{
    /**
     * Enregistre notre autoloader
     */
    static function register(){
        spl_autoload_register(array(__CLASS__, 'autoload'));
    }

    /**
     * Inclue le fichier correspondant à notre classe
     * @param $class string Le nom de la classe à charger
     */
    static function autoload($class){
        require '\\..\\'.$class . '.php';
    }

}
```

Class EquipementsManager:

```
namespace backoffice\controllers;

use backoffice\entities\Connexion;
use backoffice\entities\Equipement;

class EquipementsManager{
    //---some stuff to do----
}
```

I also tried this `__DIR__.'\\..\\'.$class . '.php'` still the same problem, works on localhost but not online.
**Edit today (20/02/2016):**
I edited my autoload() function to this:

```
static function autoload($class){
        $file = (strpos($class, 'backoffice') === false) ? $class : str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class);
        require $file . '.php';
    }
```

Now my files are loaded correctly but another error appears :

```
require(JsonSerializable.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I use `\JsonSerializable interface` to convert my objet to jason array, something like this:

```
namespace backoffice\entities;

/**
 * PropertyType
 */
class PropertyType implements \JsonSerializable
{

}
```

as you know this Interface is in SPL so why he don't know it ?!

Comment: try to change permission of the file might it work. chmod 777 path/to/file.php

Comment: Post the code of your `Autoloader.php`.

Comment: str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class). your localhost is Win, and server nix*?

Comment: @Dmitry Sorry still not working !

Comment: Try remove first slash from your path ( ../path/to/file/). Your path is absolute - '\\..\\'.$class . '.php'; - but i think it's incorrect path.

Comment: I dont understand why `'\\..\\'.$class . '.php'` works on your localhost. This references a file in the root folder of your server which would be quite unusual. Can you post the code you use to create `EquipementsManager` object?

Comment: @maxhb I posted EquipementsManager's code, please take a look.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$require = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '..\\'.$class.'.php');
require($require);
```

Comment: I'm using autoloader to avoid this and use namespace instead.

Comment: Updated. Can give it a try?